# DXA-Java on WebSphere

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

Is the DXA-Java framework supported on WebSphere? We are using WebSphere 8.5 and the only documentation I've found references Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 4):

It should work, but we only tested ourselves on Tomcat, hence the Tomcat references in the documentation.

If you run into any issues (not related to Websphere setup or configuration) please set us know by logging them on Github https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues

Comment: thanks so much for the quick response. Do you know if using WebSphere instead of Tomcat has any formal impact on the level of support on the framework?

Comment: Hi Jim, please note there currently isn't a formal support statement for DXA as mentioned in the documentation. Besides that, as mentioned, it should work and let us know if you run into issues so we can fix them if needed (we basically "support" the same application servers that SDL Tridion Content Delivery does). What I hear so far is that websphere is tricky to configure to use the right dependencies (those from DXA, and not its own defaults which are a different version). I hope somebody from the community that has it working can reply here with how they did it and what the gotchas are.

Answer (score 1):

DXA Java works on WebSphere. You do have to take care of the class loading policy and you need to clean up some of the JARs though. Ginika recently wrote this helpful blog post about this topic: [Setting Up DXA 1.7 Java Web Application on WebSphere 8.5](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/setting-up-dxa-1-7-java-web-application-on-websphere-8-5)